# How to use springsource tool suite for spring web service development?

Tags: spring-ws, sts-springsourcetoolsuite

How to use springsource tool suite for spring web service development?
quick start of how link/guidance is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link showing almost everything step by step and you can even see the famous Spring logo in the IDE showing he's using STS: http://briansjavablog.blogspot.com/2013/01/spring-web-services-tutorial.html